# Iterated optional times

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

In the following proposition of [Kallenberg's book *Foundation of Modern Probabilities*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030618704), where $\theta_t$ is the shift operator defined by $\theta_t(\omega)(s)=\omega(t+s)$,

> **Proposition 11.8** (iterated optional times) For a metric space $S$, let $σ, τ$ be optional times on the canonical space $S^∞$ endowed with
> the right-continuous, induced ﬁltration. Then we may form an optional
> time $$\gamma = \sigma + \tau\circ\theta_{\sigma}.$$

I don't really understand how the evaluation of $\gamma(\omega)$ is done? Is it $\gamma(\omega)=\sigma(\omega)+\tau(\theta_{\sigma(\omega)}(\omega))$? What is its interpretation? Why is it called iterated optional times?

Comment: $\gamma$ measures the first time $\tau$ occurs *after* $\sigma$. So $\sigma$ occurs, then $\tau$ is studied only for the process *shifted* by $\sigma$, so that we are basically looking for the time that $\tau$ occurs once $\sigma$ has occurred, and that is $\gamma$. It's iterated, because studying $\gamma$ ensures that $\tau$ is sampled only when it comes after $\sigma$, so you're first waiting for $\sigma$ then for $\tau$ after $\sigma$. Your evaluation of $\gamma$ is correct.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, thank you. I find it difficult somehow to understand that $\omega$ is the realization in $\tau(\omega)$ but in the same time $\omega$ is the stochastic process itself, i.e. $X_t(\omega)=\omega(t)$.

Comment: Will take time to adjust to, I am sure you will give it that!